# How to make ocean waves move towards a central point (Concentric Waves)

Tags: modifiers, ocean-simulation

I have a basic island and I want the ocean to move towards the island from all sides, but I want it to look natural. How can I make all the waves blend together around the island, but all going towards the same point?

Answer (score 11):

You didn't provide much information about your setup but this could do it :

Ingredients :

- [Ocean Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/physics/ocean.html)
- [Simple Deform Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/simple_deform.html)

In the ocean modifier, add divisions to the repeat X and Y properties. Expand the Waves panel, set the Alignment to 1, and the direction to 90°. Animate the time with keyframes or a driver, eg `#frame/10`.

[image]

[image]

Set the Simple deform modifier to Bend along Z axis, by 360°. It's looking like the stuff of nightmares, but we'll get to the cool part just afterwards.

[image]

Add your island in the middle :

[image]

Result :

[image]

Of course, you'll need to tweak the ocean properties to fit your project.

As pointed out in the comments, you can also use a wave modifier on a subdivided plane. The trick is to set the offset to a very high value (at least higher than your total number of frames), and set a negative speed.

[image]

Add a Texture for realism.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Very nice!!!!!!!

Comment: It certainly is!!

Comment: Hello Gorgious, Wave modifier allows to create waves from center to periphery, do you know if the direction can be inverted?

Comment: @moonboots thanks for pointing it out ! I added it to the end of the answer. Trick is to set a very high offset and speed to a negative value

Comment: ok thanks! I'm going to test that

Comment: the problem is that both the solutions are very repetitive, how could you easily break that? Using a Displacement modifier with a stretched texture works fine, except you can't join first and last array tile correctly